# jQuery RSS Audio Player - HTML5/Flash Fallback

Tags: jquery, html, audio, rss

I've searched everywhere and still can't find an answer to my dilemma.. I'm looking for a jQuery HTML5 Audio Player that is capable of playing audio RSS feeds and has a stable Flash Fallback for older browsers. Is there anything out there that is capable of performing this task? Can jPlayer be modified to play RSS feeds?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of how you want it to function, but you could use either jQuery.ajax or some other rss jQuery plugin to generate a list of the audio items, each with their own player, or play button that links to the `jPlayer( "setMedia", Object: media )` function. Or you could generate this list as a hidden list before you initialize the jPlayer and then add them all in the `jPlayer.ready` function.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, nice, I thought about this.. If I were pulling feeds from other domains and I'm in .NET, would I need to utilize a proxy to be able to pull in the data via jFeed?

Comment: If you don't need all the ajaxy goodness for loading the rss feed, it may be easier just to load and parse the feed on the server before rendering the page, perhaps with some caching to reduce page load times.

Comment: So I went ahead with utilizing jplayer and have styled it to what i need, however I will be pulling rss data from 10 different sources, so the best method i can think of is to pull the data each time on click. The issue however is that I'm not too familiar with jplayer and am having some trouble applying the newly pulled data to the playlist... since i need a playlist to first generate the player, what would be the best method in replacing the initial playlist with the new mp3 that i pull in the feed?

Comment: `$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "your_mp3_url_here"});`

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at Flowplayer hope this helps you.

http://flowplayer.org/